# Disable creation of a page for a content type and just use teasers?

Tags: 7

So on my website I have Content Type: Level 3 - Article Page. This page has two node reference fields where you can set Call to Actions, these display teaser versions of other articles, downloads etc and are shown below the body text of the page. See this screenshot:

[image]

I now want to also allow users to set Call To Actions on the Level 3 pages for specific Giving/Donations.

So I've created a new Content Type: Giving CTAs. Here a user can add text, a thumbnail, title, default donation amount etc.

The issue is that I only ever want to use these Giving CTAs as teasers rendered as in the screenshot. They will forward to a giving checkout page carrying the donation amount value.  I don't really want full pages to be rendered for each one. So is there a way to cancel the rendering of pages or disable it for this content type? Maybe it's actually disabling the creation of a URL and default node/id URL? I'm not sure :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, every Drupal node created has a "page" created for it, no matter what. You can disable the creation of a user-friendly URL, but all nodes have a node ID, and since the node/id URL path is in reality just a simple query, all nodes can have "pages" generated for them by querying against their node IDs in this way.

I would say as long as you just refrain from placing these content types into a menu, you won't need to worry about it. It's highly unlikely that a user would manipulate a URL on their own in order to find the content's page.

Comment: Could I use `drupal_goto()` to send to Page Not Found or give it that status?

Comment: Yeah I guess you could, but I'm not sure I'd go to the trouble myself to be honest.